# How to load terms in alphabetical order or in the same order they are in CMS?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am loading terms programmatically but I am hoping to load them in the same order as they show in the CMS (weight). If not that, I just want them to load in alphabetical order.

This is what I am doing:

```
$vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($name);
$terms = entity_load('taxonomy_term', FALSE, array('vid' => $vocabulary->vid));
```

Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: If you look at [entity_load manual](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_load/7)  you will see the conditions array is depracated in favor of EntityFieldQuery, which should be able to achieve the sorting you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For getting all child terms in a vocabulary try the following code.

```
$cc=array();
$tax=taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($name);
$vid= $tax->vid;
$child_terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);
foreach($child_terms as $values) {
  $tname=$values->name;
  $cc[] = $tname; 
}
```

The above code will give you child terms of that vocabulary in array `$cc`. For sorting in alphabetical order use `asort($cc);`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @longboardnode's comment, you can use EntityFieldQuery to retrieve the desired results set in the order that you specify.

You can then get the Term IDs from the results set, and pass that into entity_load() to get your term entities.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term');
$query->entityCondition('bundle', $machine_name);
$query->propertyOrderBy('weight');
$query->propertyOrderBy('name');
$result = $query->execute();

$tids = array_keys($result['taxonomy_term']);
$terms = entity_load('taxonomy_term', $tids);
```